# Only allow root to do su specific user

Tags: redhat, rhel6

I'm on RHEL 6.8

I have a user "myuser" with sudoer rights and other users with no sudoers rights.

Can I only allow root to do a "su myuser" in local ?

Thank you

Comment: No, you can't. root can do whatever he wants.

Comment: Hello Actually it is not my problem. There is no problem to let root become "myuser", but I don't want other users to become "myuser".

Comment: Well, that's not what you are asking in the question. Anyway, the only way for "otheruser" to su to "myuser" is by knowing the password of "myuser". In that case the user can just log in as "myuser". What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, once you allow a user to become root, short of using `SELinux` there's *no way to restrict them*. Which is why you shouldn't hand out root permissions willy-nilly.

I'd recommend moving away from `su` to `sudo`.

That being said, you *could* cook up something with `gpasswd` and `pam_wheel.so`, but at best it might break scripts and at worst it's a security risk:

Use `pam_wheel` in `/etc/pam.d/su`.

Quoting `man pam_wheel`:

```
NAME
       pam_wheel - Only permit root access to members of group wheel

SYNOPSIS
       pam_wheel.so [debug] [deny] [group=name] [root_only] [trust] [use_uid]
[...]
group=name
       Instead of checking the wheel or GID 0 groups, use the name group to perform the authentication.
```

References:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/601682/restrict-su-to-a-group-of-users

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
Actually your link and your exemple are short but obvious, I've been able to understand now. Thank you :)